# Is the initial Constructor initialization and invocation is done at run-time or compile time

Tags: java, constructor

Can anyone please tell me when will the initial Constructor initialization and invocation is been done. Is  it happens at compile time or run-time. Even though i believe that it happens at run time, but when one asked about, how compiler will check the parent-child relation ship without constructor initialization i got confused. for example

we have a parent class `College` and child class `Department`

**EDIT**

```
class College
{ 
  public String getCollegeName()
  {
   return "ABC College";
  }
}

class Department extends College
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    College s = new Department();
    System.out.println(s.getCollegeName());
    System.out.println(s.getDepartName());
  }

  public String getDepartName()
  {
   return "IT Department";
  }
}
```

here without invoking `Department s = new College()` how could compiler knows that s has a `getDepartName()` method which is been derived.

Comment: Still trying to work out your question to see where your confusion lies - but the answer is the constructor is run at run-time.

Comment: This won't work. Did you mean `Department d = new College()`?

Comment: `public void getCollegeName()`.. should be `public String ..`

Comment: @Axel yes it is `Department d = new College()`

Comment: because the compiler knows `Department extends College`, is that your question?

Comment: @RC means  `new College()` is not been invoked by compiler

Comment: nope the compiler compiles, it doesn't invoke anything

Comment: Sorry, my fault, but that's still wrong. You cannot do `Department s = new College()` because College is the base class. You could however `College s = new Department()`.

Comment: @Axel Ok now see if `College s = new Department()` is been done without invoking `new Department()` how could the compiler knows s has `s.getDepartName()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens at run-time. "How could compiler knows that s has a getCollegeName() method which is been derived." - because compiler knows that s is an instance of College and College has method getCollegeName(). You told that s is an instance of College with

```
College s
```

If you do

```
Object s = new College();
```

then you can only invoke methods that Object has because compiler has no way of knowing that s is College

Comment: OK then if College s = new Department() is been done, and  without invoking new Department() how could the compiler knows s has s.getDepartName() method

Comment: it does not know that. It will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is in some way a special case. In a non trivial program you can  typically not determine the class of the object a certain reference points to better than "it is of the type the reference was declared for or a subtype of it".

The whole concept of polymorphism is based on the fact that the concrete class is only known at runtime but not at compile time. This of course means that the compiler must ensure that the methods that are called on a reference will be available on the referenced object at runtime. The only methods for which this holds true are the methods of the class for which the variable was declared (including all inherited methods from the super classes).

Answer (score 1):

`s` is declared with the type `Department`, and the compiler already knows `Department` is inherited from `College`, and so all methods declared in `Department` and `College` (because `Department` is derived from `College`) can be called.

This works, because you are not allowed to assign anything (except `null`) to `s` that is not a `Department` or of a class derived from it.

There's no need to execute the constructor, because everything can be determined based on the declared type of `s`.

Comment: ok at compile time if `College s` is invoked at not  `new Department();` , as for the time s is `College` class and `College` class don't have `getDepartName()` method. then in this case what will compiler do??

Comment: It all depends on the declared type. If you use `College s`, only methods declared in `College` can be called. If you use `Department s`, methods declared in `Department` and `College` (because it is the base class) can be called.